# Angular get router without mapped parameters on navigation end

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-routing

I am currently facing a problem with angular where I am subscribing to router events and I am trying to get the URL without the mapped parameters. The reason for this being that we are storing page visits but for storage sake we have a relation that is `pages` and we went to store the url without the parameters so we only have one record, we then store the parameters inside of another field within the database.

The issue that I am currently facing, and I’ve seen answers on here that refer to using the `routeConfig` but as I am currently within another module/a child route the `routePath` within is always a empty string.

Essentially what I am hoping to achieve is if I have a url such as `/products/1` I want to get the raw url from it without the parameters so it would be `/products/:id`.

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event: RouterEvent) => {
    // I need to get the url here without the params mapped.

    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        // Logic here to track.
    }
});
```

Also a side note is that when I have previously listened for the `ActivationEnd` and targeted the `firstChild` property on the `event.state` it doesn't seem to either have the full URL or its not got any of the parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the params from the activated route.

```
constructor(private router: Router, route: ActivatedRoute) {  
  this.router.events.pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
    ).subscribe((event: NavigationEnd) => {
        // I need to get the url here without the params mapped.
        let url = event.url;
        const params = route.snapshot.params;
        const properties = Object.entries(params);
        properties.reverse();
        for (const p of properties) {
            url = url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
            url = `${url}/:${p[0]}`;
        }
        console.log(url);
    });
  }
```

Comment: This wouldn't give me the parameters in the url format that I specified? `/products/':id'`